# Chaining Object.

Tags: javascript, chaining, prototype-programming

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how to chain objects the way I would like to do it.

Lets the following example:

```
var s = function(){
    this.text = {
        hi: function(){
            //do something
            return new s().text;
        }
    };
    return null;
};

var a = new s();
```

Lets say where the `//do something` is, you have some sort of code that does something (returns something). You want to return that results while still allow people to chain more functions to the results.

However, if I would return something, something like:

```
console.log(a.text.hi().hi());
```

Wouldn't work anymore because the last return (`new s().text`) wont be returned because, you can't return two things, I understand that.

My main question is, is it possible to do chaining where you can chain another function to the results of the previous one but if no function is chained to the previous one return the results.

My only solution I found was using a syntax like:

```
a.text.hi().hi().end;
```

In order to instruct the code to return the last functions results. However, I don't find this very practical and I hope there is a better way to accomplish what i'm wanting to do.

Comment: No, I don't think there is a way to do this. As you said you can always only return one value and also you don't know how a value is going to be used. Having a method that returns the final result seems to be good enough approach to me.